# How to make a for loop iterate a list and ask for input? PYTHON

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I would like to make a program that asks how many bills of each type you got, to do this I wanted to use a for loop and a list.

I did this little test:

```
types_of_bills = [2, 5, 10]

for i in types_of_bills:
    amount_of_bills = int(input("How many {}$ bills have you got?".format(types_of_bills)[i])))
```

This only prints, not all three choices as I want:

```
How many 10$ bills have you got?
```

And when I give any input it gives me this error:

```
cantidad_de_billetes = int(input("How many {}$ have you got?".format(bills[i])))
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use index like - `(types_of_bills)[i]`, you can just use `i` -

```
types_of_bills = [2, 5, 10]

for i in types_of_bills:
    amount_of_bills = int(input("How many {}$ bills have you got? ".format(i)))
```

Output -

```
How many 2$ bills have you got? 1
How many 5$ bills have you got? 2
How many 10$ bills have you got? 3
```

You will get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`, because of giving input something other than a `integer`

Also, instead of `.format`, you can use `f-strings` because it is much easier to read -

```
amount_of_bills = int(input(f"How many {i}$ bills have you got? "))
```

Check this out - [Python 3 f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)